# DynamoDB Downscales within the last 24 hours?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, scalability, amazon-dynamodb

Is it anyhow possible to get the count, how often DynamoDB throughput (write units/read units) was downscaled within the last 24 hours?

My idea is to downscale as soon as an hugo drop e.g. 50% in the needed provisioned write units occur. I have really peaky traffic. Thus it is interessting to me to downscale after every peak. However I have a analytics jobs running at night which is provisioning a huge amount of read units making it necessary to be able to downscale after it. Thus I need to limit downscales to 3 times within 24 hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of decreases is returned in a [DescribeTable](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeTable.html) result as part of the [ProvisionedThroughputDescription](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_ProvisionedThroughputDescription.html#DDB-Type-ProvisionedThroughputDescription-NumberOfDecreasesToday).